# How to get `Fri Oct 25 2019` from a date object (Fri Oct 25 2019 15:27:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))?

Tags: javascript, date, methods

How can I get `Fri Oct 25 2019` from a `date` object as below?

```
Fri Oct 25 2019 15:27:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `toDateString()` function from JavaScript.

```js
let d = new Date();

// note : the actual display output depend on your browser/system settings (locale)
console.log(d.toString());
console.log(d.toDateString());
```

This will take the first "date only" part of the string that is displayed from the date object.

It could also be done with string manipulation, but this function is actually intended for this usecase, so probably clearer.

[Doc for `toDateString` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString)

Comment: I think you are incorrect about the locale. [MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString) that the output of `toDateString` at least will always look like this. Usually in JS if you want locale dependent strings there is a [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) function. For dates there also is [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString).

Comment: @H.B. thanks for checking. Seems right, I corrected my answer.